# Comparing dynamic objects in C#

Tags: c#, dynamic

What is the best way to compare two arbitrary dynamic objects for equality? For example these two objects.

I.e.

```
dynamic obj1 = new ExpandoObject();
obj1.Name = "Marcus";
obj1.Age = 39;
obj1.LengthInMeters = 1.96;

dynamic obj2 = AMethodReturningADynamic();
obj2.Name = "Marcus";
obj2.Age = 39;
obj2.LengthInMeters = 1.96;

Assert.AreEqual(obj1, obj2); // ?
```

Or is there a way to get the actual properties and their values as lists? To create an ExpandoObject from a dynamic type for example?

Comment: Hmmm - I think I've looked at this wrong. I might have to create a class for my object and inherit from DynamicObject (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.trygetmember.aspx). Then I can use methods like GetDynamicMemberNames (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.getdynamicmembernames.aspx) and TryGetMember(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.trygetmember.aspx) to query and compare the objects.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Microsoft API's for dynamically invoking methods and propertys on arbitrary dynamic objects (IDynamicMetaObjectProvider) are not easy to use when you don't have the compiler's help. You can use [Dynamitey](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey) (via nuget) to simplify this completely. It has a  static function  [Dynamic.InvokeGet](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding#dynamic-dynamicinvokegetobject-target-string_or_invokemembername-name) to call property's getters with just a target and a property name.

To get a list of properties of the dynamic object, there is a bit of a gotcha, as the dynamic object has to support it (if it's a DynamicObject that means implementing GetDynamicMemberNames, Expando supports it, but random IDynamicMetaObjectProvider may not and just return an empty list). Dynamitey has a method to simplifying getting those names as well, [Dynamic.GetMemberNames](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding#ienumerablestring-getmembernamesobject-target-bool-dynamiconly--false).

Both of those two functions give you the basic tools necessary to compare many arbitrary dynamic objects via properties.

```
//using System.Dynamic;
//using Dynamitey;
//using System.Linq;

IEnumerable<string> list1 =Dynamic.GetMemberNames(obj1);
list1 = list1.OrderBy(m=>m);
IEnumerable<string> list2 =Dynamic.GetMemberNames(obj2);
list2 = list2.OrderBy(m=>m);

if(!list1.SequenceEqual(list2))
 return false;

foreach(var memberName in list1){
 if(!Dynamic.InvokeGet(obj1, memberName).Equals(Dynamic.InvokeGet(obj2,memberName))){
    return false;
 }
}
return true;
```

However, if they are just your own DynamicObject subclass then it'd be easier to just follow the typical [rules for implementing Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h9bszxx.aspx), there really is no difference from non-dynamic objects, and just compare what you are internally using for state.

Comment: Whooa - this looks great. I'll check it out for my usage and get back to you

Comment: Dude - that totally worked great! See my usage here: https://github.com/marcushammarberg/SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic . Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: I see an Equals method for the ExpandoObject.... like System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject.Equals(obj1, obj2); Will this suffice?

Comment: @zak what you see is only the Equals method inherited from System.Object. So, no it won't compare two separate Expando's--let alone, an Expando and another DLR object. https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Actions/ExpandoObject.cs

Answer (score 12):

`ExpandoObject` implements `ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` (in addition to `IDictionary` and `IEnumerable` of the same), so you should be able to compare them property by property pretty easily:

```
public static bool AreExpandosEquals(ExpandoObject obj1, ExpandoObject obj2)
{
    var obj1AsColl = (ICollection<KeyValuePair<string,object>>)obj1;
    var obj2AsDict = (IDictionary<string,object>)obj2;

    // Make sure they have the same number of properties
    if (obj1AsColl.Count != obj2AsDict.Count)
        return false;

    foreach (var pair in obj1AsColl)
    {
        // Try to get the same-named property from obj2
        object o;
        if (!obj2AsDict.TryGetValue(pair.Key, out o))
            return false;

        // Property names match, what about the values they store?
        if (!object.Equals(o, pair.Value))
            return false;
    }

    // Everything matches
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Great answer - but my question was misleading. I was trying to compare to dynamic objects. The fact that they were ExpandoObject was just my example of creating the dynamic object. Arbitrary dynamic objects do not appear to expose enumerators, as Raymond answered.

Comment: How would you expand this example to support recursion? ExpandoObjects usually have children of type ExpandoObject. Can we use this for multi level ExpandoObjects? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

See "Enumerating and deleting members" to get the members of an ExpandoObject http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx

Arbitrary dynamic objects do not appear to expose enumerators, though.

Comment: Thank you - my question was not properly asked but you got it. I was asking about arbitrary dynamic objects.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.icomparable%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)-Interface. Then you have the appropriate functions needed from .NET/C# to compare two objects with each other.

Comment: Great answer - but my question was misleading. I was trying to compare to dynamic objects. The fact that they were ExpandoObject was just my example of creating the dynamic object. Arbitrary dynamic objects do not appear be able to do that as Raymond answered

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the ObjectsComparer library available on GitHub :
[ObjectsComparer](https://github.com/ValeraT1982/ObjectsComparer)

This library is an object-to-object comparer that allows us to compare objects recursively member by member and to define custom comparison rules for certain properties, fields or types. It supports enumerables (arrays, collections, lists), multidimensional arrays, enumerations, flags and dynamic objects (ExpandoObject, DynamicObject and compiler generated dynamic objects).

Go to  [Valerii Tereshchenko](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-objects-comparer-to-compare-complex-objects-in-c-sharp/) excellent paper for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Expando Objects are useable as an `IDictonary<string, object>` so you should be able to use that.

Something like

```
Assert.AreEqual((IDictonary(object, string))obj1, (IDictonary(object, string))obj2);
```

*Edit* the `AreEqual` won't work.

But you could try comparing the two dictionaries fairly simply.

Comment: Great answer - but my question was misleading. I was trying to compare to dynamic objects. The fact that they were ExpandoObject was just my example of creating the dynamic object. Arbitrary dynamic objects do not appear to expose enumerators, as Raymond answered